# Node's Preview when using Views module to render Node

Tags: views, nodes, display-suite, entities

I have been using Views module to render Node's Full content (using unformatted list of fields!). Seems that was not such a good idea.

Now when I preview the Node, I see the Teaser and Full content Entity view modes (instead a View with fields). So the actual problem is these teasers and Full content are not themed the way my View is.

Is there any workaroud except rebuilding the whole thing in Display Suite module?

THX!

Comment: Yes, for sure there is ;) But that's all the answer we can give you until you will tell us how you configured views to take over your nodes. And what does it mean "I cannot"? Please tell / show us what exactly happens when you try.

Comment: @Molot the thing is I have been using the Unformatted List of Fields (instead Full posts/teasers) for building my View. Now when I preview the Node, I see the Teaser and Full content Entity view modes (instead a View with fields). So the actual problem is these teasers and Full content are not themed the way my View is. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: Please [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/95051/edit) to provide details. Details in comments may easily be overlooked or die in a comments purge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to rebuild the whole thing in Display Suite module. Views (when using Unformatted List of Fields) cannot render teaser and Full content in node's preview!